# Android SQLite query super slow

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite, cursor

I have a database with one table and about 350.000 rows in there. When I try to query them it's super slow on my Nexus4. The `cursor.moveToFirst()` method call takes about 500ms. If I run the exact same query on the same database in my terminal using sqlite3 it takes about 10ms. So I suppose that my `Cursor` is not using my index...

```
String table = "table";

String[] columns = {
         "col1",
         "col2"
};

String predicate = "col1 like '?' and col2 = ?";

String[] values = {
         value1+"%%",
         value2
};

String orderBy = "col3 ASC";

String limit = "5";

Cursor c = this.mDatabase.query(table, columns, predicate, values, null, null, orderBy, limit);

if (c != null) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  c.moveToFirst();
  long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
  // The duration here is super slow
  ....
}
```

The database has an index on `col1` and `col2`. And like I said... when executing the sql in the command line it's super fast... about 10ms vs 500 on my phone...

Any ideas on how I can improve the speed on that query? Is seems as if the index isn't used?!?

Thanks

Comment: `executing the sql in the command line it's super fast... about 10ms vs 500 on my phone...` - So, are you really pretending that your phone has the same speed as your PC?

Comment: of course not... but the difference is quite huge, isn't it? any a simple query taking 500ms on the phone? that's just not ok ...

Comment: It depends on the phone. I've tried very huge databases for some tablet applications. It results that Genymotion (an emulator based on Virtual Box) works better than tablets. Sqlite isn't as powerfull as SQL for several reasons, for example "views" are not implemented in the same way. However I could improve the queries using indexes, have a look at the documentation of Sqlite https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html. Maybe a restructuration of the data. Apps are not thinked to manage huge databases, that is the reality.

Comment: so you don't see a mistake in my code? nothing to do for indexes?

Comment: Indexes are set. On iOS the same DB works super fast...
The %% only after the word should mean "starts with" (The second % is because of the character escaping... even though I just tried... one would also work, but makes no difference in speed :( )

Comment: Removing the quotes also doesn't change speed...
I don't think that the difference between iOS Code and Android code is THAT significant?!? It seems as if Android is just ignoring my index...

Comment: Well, could be that android is ignoring indexes. Maybe another insight could be this. If you set the index to col1 and col2 together the index table is a hashmap of the two combined. An index is a hashmap that allows a dicotomic search in log(n) but you are using  "like" in col1 so the framework have to compare all the n rows and index is not usefull. Maybe IOS manage to internally use the index in a better way. Maybe you can prove to create two indexes, one for col1 and another for col2. But i'm not sure it is just an idea.